# Como resolvo o problema Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cells' of undefined neste contexto?

Tags: javascript, undefined

Eis o código onde diz que está undefined:

```js
function verifica_pos(row, col){
 //Move para Sul
 if (document.getElementById("table").rows[row - 3].cells[col].innerHTML == count_num - 1) {
  return true;
 }else if (document.getElementById("table").rows[row - 2].cells[col + 2].innerHTML == count_num - 1) { //Move para Sudoeste
  return true;
 }else if (document.getElementById("table").rows[row].cells[col + 3].innerHTML == count_num - 1) { //Move para Oeste
  return true;
 }else if (document.getElementById("table").rows[row + 2].cells[col + 2].innerHTML == count_num - 1) { //Move para Noroeste
  return true;
 }else if (document.getElementById("table").rows[row + 3].cells[col].innerHTML == count_num - 1) { //Move para Norte
  return true;
 }else if (document.getElementById("table").rows[row + 2].cells[col - 2].innerHTML == count_num - 1) {//Move para Nordeste
  return true;
 }else if (document.getElementById("table").rows[row].cells[col - 3].innerHTML == count_num - 1) { //Move para Este
  return true;
 }else if (document.getElementById("table").rows[row - 2].cells[col - 2].innerHTML == count_num - 1) { //Move para Sudeste
  return true;
 }else{
  return false;
 }
}
```

Em que count_num é uma variável do tipo Number que contém um número de 1 a 100.

Comment: É uma tabela de 100 células? 10 linhas e 10 colunas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acontece que você está tentando acessar um elemento inexistente na tabela, seja uma coluna ou uma linha. Por exemplo, se você tentar acessar a propriedade `.cells` de uma `.rows` inexistente, irá retornar o erro citado na pergunta.

O valor do índice em `.rows` deve estar no range de `0` ao número de linhas -1, ou seja, se a tabela tem 10 linhas, o valor dentro dos colchetes de `.rows[]` deve ser de `0` a `9`. Por exemplo, se o valor do parâmetro `row` da função for `1`, irá dar erro logo no primeiro `if` onde você colocou `.rows[row - 3]`, que será `.rows[1 - 3]`, resultando em `.rows[-2]`. O valor `-2` é não está dentre `0` e `9`.

Neste caso você deve fazer duas verificações antes de tentar acessar a propriedade `.innerHTML`: verificar se a `.rows` existe e depois o `.cells`, mais ou menos nesse esquema:

```
if(row existe){
   if(coluna existe){
      if(innerHTML == count - 1){
         return true;
      }
   }
}
```

Repare que para cada verificação você teria que fazer 2 `if`'s até chegar no `if` que acessa a propriedade `.innerHTML`. Como são várias verificações, o código ficaria muito extenso.

Refiz o código de uma forma que a função `verifica_pos` retorna `false` em dois 
casos: se a célula não existe **ou** se a célula existe mas o `.innerHTML` dela não bate com `count_num - 1`.

Veja:

```
function move(r,c){
   var table = document.getElementById("table");
   var l = table.rows.length;
    if ( r >= 0 && r < l && c >= 0 && c < table.rows[r].cells.length ){
      if(table.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML == count_num - 1) return true;
   }
   return false;
}

function verifica_pos(row, col){

   var r, c;

    //Move para Sul
   r = row-3, c = col;
   if(move(r,c)) return true;

   //Move para Sudoeste
   r = row-2, c = col+2;
   if(move(r,c)) return true;

   //Move para Oeste
   r = row, c = col+3;
   if(move(r,c)) return true;

   //Move para Noroeste
   r = row+2, c = col+2;
   if(move(r,c)) return true;

   //Move para Norte
   r = row+3, c = col;
   if(move(r,c)) return true;

   //Move para Nordeste
   r = row+2, c = col-2;
   if(move(r,c)) return true;

   //Move para Este
   r = row, c = col-3;
   if(move(r,c)) return true;

   return false;
}
```